# Using Java ExecutorCompletionService and Postgres inserts via MyBatis

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

I thought I would be clever and am using an ExecutorCompletionService to parallelize tasks that insert a bunch of records into a Postgres database. Motly it works great and I can see an increase in performance. However, now and then it fails with a primary key exception.. most likely due to concurrent threads trying to create records at the same time. Is there a graceful way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some coordinated and thread safe way to generate primary keys. The best option if your primary key is numeric is to user database sequence - it is safe and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my original problem had to do with the sequence being different from the record count of the table. In fact Postgres can create new unique id's concurrently as far as I can tell. No additional coding needs to be done.